# adding a clipart from png file

Tags: c#, bmp

I have a problem adding cliparts (from png files) to bmp object. I add some cliparts to a jpeg image and after I save it, I get a mistery: some cliparts are present in saved image, but some not.

Here is code how I add cliparts to image:

```
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(this._image))
        {
            gfx.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;


            gfx.DrawImage(image, posX, posY, newWidth, newHeight);
            gfx.Save();
        }
```

Can anybode explain what am I doing wrong or why this situation appears?

edited:
it happens when I use this code inside a ASP.NET Application, when I use it in windows application everything is fine

Comment: You added information that the issue occurs only when You use the code in ASP.NET application. Please write more about how You load the main image, the clipart images and how you save the final image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of Your issue, but line `gfx.Save()` does not save the image you painted back to the image, but saves state of the `Graphics` object. In order to save the changes back to the image, make sure to call `Image.Save()` method and double check to make sure You are not restoring the previous image somewhere in the code. More information about it `Graphics.Save` method can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.save(v=vs.100).aspx.

**Update**

You wrote in the comments that it's a transparency issue. If this is the cause, take a look at the code loading the clipart images from files. This also may be caused by various pixel formats used in your image files. Changing You images loading algorithm to something like this may solve the issue:

- load your background image, let's say it's done like this: `Image backgroundImg = new Bitmap(backgroundImgPath);`
- create a new empty image as a base for all the images: `this._image = new Bimap(backgroundImg.Width, backgroundImg.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);`
- draw the contents of `backgroundImg` onto `this._image` with `gfx.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;`
- then, you can draw the cliparts as You're doing it now (just comment out `gfx.Save();` method)

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: as I understand, after it saves the state all my cliparts must be present in the image, but in my case something goes wrong

Comment: I suppose that saving the `Graphics` object is not required, because it is disposed right after that. The issue is rather  in a different part of code i.e. code applying new clipart.

Comment: I digged more into this and noticed that cliparts are present in the image but there opacity is very high (they are too transparent). This makes me more confused... How they become transparent?? still have to dig into

Comment: It may be a pixel format issue. Take a look at my updated answer.